Double tyre for a turbo trainer
I was wondering about a way in which I can use a tyre system with a turbo trainer such that I can easily swap from turbo trainer to road without much work.
The idea is to use the turbo trainer maybe some days during the week when I get back from work late in the evening and then ride the bike outside during the weekend.
Would having a cheap tyre over the main tyre work? Like a cover tyre. Or some type of tape that would protect the tyre and that I can easily remove when I want to go to ride during the weekend?
If the double tyre system could work, would it be best that the "cover tyre" be the same size (700x25) as the main tyre, or would having it smaller/bigger have any advantage?
Thanks

If you don't already own a turbo trainer, you can buy "wheel off" trainers. These are more expensive, but the option exists.

You're not going to be able to install a second tire over an existing tire.
Your best bet will be to find an inexpensive second rear wheel (doesn't need to be light or durable) and use that for your trainer rides.
Swapping rear wheels may sound like a hassle. But after you do it a few times, my guess is you'll get it down to taking about 20 seconds.

Agreed. You can even buy special turbo-trainer tires that resist wear better.
